# Reinitialize Appwork theme event listeners

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm using this bootstrap based theme (Appwork in my Rails frontend. But due to turbolinks all the event listeners (like collapsing menus) stop working after clicking any link. At the moment I can't just disable turbolinks.

I've went through the [layout helper docs](https://uxpowered.com/products/appwork/v100/html-demo/layouts_helpers.html) but still could not make this work.

Any idea how I reinitialize those listeners for that theme?

[Theme demo link](https://uxpowered.com/products/appwork/v100/html-demo/ui_sidenav.html).

Here's the code snippet:

```
// Vendors
//= require bootstrap-v4/import
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker
//= require appwork-theme/import

$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  // <----- insert solution to reactivate sidenav-toggle here
});
```

Comment: On the docks you shared it says that it calls the `init()` method when the page loads, have you tried calling that manually inside your `turbolinks:load` callback? `window.layoutHelpers.init()`

Comment: @arieljuod yes, I did, did not help